# When is an F# `do` statement in a module evaluated?

Tags: f#

I'm a little confused with when exactly things are supposed to evaluate.

I have file A.fs:

```
type MyType = { ... }

do System.Console.Write("A.fs")
```

In file B.fs:

```
let x : A.MyType = { ... }
do System.Console.Write("B.fs")
```

I would expect to see `A.fs` printed sometime before `B.fs`. But `"A.fs"` is not actually printed at all.

I don't know if it's related, but A.fs and B.fs are in different libraries.

What are the rules for when `do`s at a top-level scope in module A are executed? Am I not able to rely on `do`s in module B being run before I can use the types and functions from module A (which calls B)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also surprised that `do` statements sometimes don't get evaluated. See my question on the [F# repo](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/13905). It seems to be according to spec.

see [FSharp language specification 4.1](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf), 12.5.1 execution of static initializers.

Answer (score 4):

It happens at the time of first reference to the module from anywhere else.

F# modules are compiled as .NET static classes, and all their `do` lines are put in the static constructor. Static constructors in .NET are executed when the class is "loaded", which happens the first time somebody tries to access anything in the class.

As a general rule, you shouldn't rely on the `do` lines for arbitrary side-effects. Ideally you shouldn't have them at all, but if you must, limit their functionality to initializing stuff that's directly required for the module to function.

Comment: OK, so if I don't see that happening, it's a compiler bug?

Comment: No. If you don't see that happening, it means you're not accessing the module.

Comment: So im my example above, where I see "B.fs" but not "A.fs", am I not accessing the module A somehow?

Comment: That is correct. I can't tell you anything more, because I don't see the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks, looks like a bug somewhere. I'll see if I can make a minimal test case and report it upstream.

Comment: @PaulBiggar did you resolve this? I asked it again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73714025/when-is-an-f-do-statement-in-a-module-evaluated-with-example